# Did I get Lateral pelvic tilt from left leg overuse?

Tags: orthopedics, knee, physical-therapy, different-national-health, leg-length-discrepancy

Almost 2 years ago I got a knee injury (ACL and meniscal tear) which left me with a mechanically locked knee for more than a month. I could still walk normally without much instability. Fortunately, my doctor suggested physiotherapy which got back the original knee movement and restored part of the muscle strength (not full strength though)

Right after that, I got a scholarship to a PhD program in China so I didn't do anything to it at first. Last year I rechecked with 2 doctors in somewhat reputable hispitals in Xi'an China, both of them concluded after checking my MRI results and performing physical tests that surgery isn't needed (or that it is not worth it) but I will have to stay away from competetive sports.

Now my concern is mostely related to my healthy knee, which hurts me when I put weight on it or if I do activities like jogging.

So to get to my question : 
is it possible that my injured leg got a bit longer (maybe caused by weak muscles or loose ligament)?
Or is it that I relied on my left side for too long until its muscles became tight which developped a lateral pelvic tilt?
If that's the case, should I see a doctor? Or someone with other profession (could you offer an exact name of the profession, so I try to translate it to Chinese)

Recap :
- Injured right knee with weak muscles.
- Left leg feels shorter (or right leg longer) which causes pain in healthy (Left) knee.
Question : who should I check with? (Should I visit another hospital, somekind of physiotherapy place, bodybuilding coach,..)